# Outlets and Actions in IOS

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS development and have a question.

I wanted to know what is the role of the Outlet and Action in IOS development?

I have tried searching online but just found examples. I wanted some background information about this so I have better knowledge on Outlets and Actions before I dig into coding.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain this to me or direct me to an online source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IBOutlet a way to mark a property that is defined (usually) within your UIViewController (or descendant) to allow access to/from a view object created within the Interface Builder (hence the "IB").

An IBAction a way to mark a method that is defined (usually) within your UIViewController (or descendant) to allow access to/from a view object (UIButton, etc) created within the Interface Builder (hence the "IB").

Answer (score 1):

have a look here, very well explained. With 2 minutes of time, you've found it by yourself.
[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

Comment: Dito. Mattt Thompson is a great developer.

Comment: Haha, I would be glad :D